# Markdown extension for really small tiny text?

Tags: feature-request, markdown

So one feature that I really wish markdown had was support for <sub><sup>really small tiny text</sup></sub>. Which I just produced by using the `<sup>` tag. I think this could be implemented by using the caret symbol like so:

`So this is normal text ^and this is tiny text^.`

Is this a reasonable feature request? Also what ideas do you have for markdown expansion?

Comment: And how about `<sub>`? And `<small>`? IIRC the request to add `<small>` was denied. But you can (ab)use `<sup><sub>` for this.

Comment: @BalusC: Well I just want tiny text in general. I wouldn't mind if they used my `^` symbol and just applied some CSS to make the text smaller. I don't really care if the text is actually above or below the normal text.

Comment: @Jon: WOW! I just looked at your edit and I can't believe I spelled it like that.

Comment: Haha, did you manage to grab any lettuce for your carrots?

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40035/allow-the-small-tag and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26756/how-do-i-use-a-small-font-size-in-questions-and-answers

Comment: Already exists in WikiText.

Answer (score 187, accepted):

Workaround: have you tried <sub><sup>combining the `<sup>` and `<sub>`</sup></sub> tags?

If you layer them like this, `<sub><sup>combining the two tags</sup></sub>`, you get tiny text that's almost in line with the normal text. Nice for making very small caveats to your answers!

Comment: Thanks for the idea, but still thats **a lot of typing!**

Comment: Clever. For some reason I always pictured them canceling each other out, which is patent nonsense

Comment: @Jared, What's the browser compatibility like?

Comment: @MichaelMrozek Why is it patent nonsense? Still confused as to why exactly they don't.

Comment: @Hashim They both make the text smaller, just the positioning is different, so nesting them is going to shrink the text twice

Comment: Order is important here. `<sup><sub>...</sub></sup>` was a bit above center. The suggested `<sub><sup>...</sup></sub>` was more centered.

Answer (score 57):

`<sub>`+`<sup>` seems like a horrible answer, really. You're mangling your HTML markup to get a particular display style with completely different semantic meaning — and you're assuming default display implementations of `<sub>` and `<sup>` while you're at it.

I would love a `<small>` or "footnote" markdown syntax too (that's how I got here), but as far as I can tell, the only reasonable way to add it to your documents is using the HTML tag itself.

Comment: `<Pedantry>`Its not HTML markup its Markdown `</Pedantry>`

Comment: Ha, well if you're using tags and not Markdown syntax, it's HTML. You can use both in the same context.

Answer (score 52):

Normal text
<sub><sup>Small text</sup></sub>
<sub><sup><sub><sup>Tiny text</sup></sub></sup></sub>
<sub><sup><sub><sup><sub><sup><sub><sup><sub><sup><sub><sup><sub><sup><sub><sup>REALLY SMALL TEXT</sup></sub></sup></sub></sup></sub></sup></sub></sup></sub></sup></sub></sup></sub></sup></sub>

is:

```
Normal text
<sub><sup>Small text</sup></sub>
<sub><sup><sub><sup>Tiny text</sup></sub></sup></sub>
<sub><sup><sub><sup><sub><sup><sub><sup><sub><sup><sub><sup><sub><sup><sub><sup>REALLY SMALL TEXT</sup></sub></sup></sub></sup></sub></sup></sub></sup></sub></sup></sub></sup></sub></sup></sub>
```