# How to make text smaller?

Tags: support, font-size

Also, can you explain on [editing help](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help) how to do so.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40035/allow-the-small-tag

Comment: duplicate of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26756/how-do-i-use-a-small-font-size-in-questions-and-answers

Answer (score 1):

Use the `<sup>` and `<sub>` tags

<sup>Such as this one (this uses sup)</sup>

And

<sub>Such as this one (this uses sub)</sub>

Note on the code for the 2nd one

```
<sub>Such as this one (this uses sub)</sub>
```

Comment: Maybe "abuse" is a better description than "use".

Comment: @arjan There are some fairly decent uses of it as has been discussed here before

Comment: Even in your comment "abuses" would be suitable I'm afraid. (But indeed, I abuse it myself too often too!)

Comment: @Arjan, "retrofit" would be a better word.