# How to apply a HTML tag to the entire post and type it only once?

Tags: support, markdown

I read [How do I use a small font size in questions and answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26756/how-do-i-use-a-small-font-size-in-questions-and-answers) and [Allow the <small> tag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/40035/226001), but I don't want to write `<sup> </sup>` for each paragraph. For example, I want everything below the line to be in a small font, but it fails. First, A fails to be quoted in yellow. Second, neither A or B are smaller.

---

<sub>>A</sub>

> B

---

Raw:

```
<sub> >A

>B </sub>
```

Comment: Why would you want to apply `<sup>` to an entire post in the first place? And it is a *inline tag*, meaning it doesn't apply to blocks anyway.

Comment: In short: it's not possible.

Answer (score 5):

The `sub` and the `sup` tag are not meant to make text smaller but:

> The sup element represents a superscript and the sub element
>   represents a subscript.

<sub>http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-sub-and-sup-elements</sub> (← Wrong use of `sub`)

They are desgined to be "Text Level Semantics" and so they are inline tags and can't be wrapped around a `blockquote`. (And it would make no sense if you could)

They are intetended to be used like:

> C<sub>6</sub>H<sub>12</sub>O<sub>6</sub>