# How can I make regular words small?

Tags: discussion, markdown

I want to make words small (like image credits), and I tried all the available edit buttons for words. How can I make regular words small?

Comment: [Duplicate](https://google.com/search?q=site%3Ameta.stackexchange.com+small+text) of [How do I use a small font size in questions and answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/26756/289905). Also included in [What HTML tags are allowed on Stack Exchange sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/135909/289905), linked from the [editing help](https://meta.stackexchange.com/editing-help), linked from the [tag wiki](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/markdown/info) of the Markdown tag.

Comment: The answers on that question is on this one, and it should have been marked as duplicate before answer. @SebastianSimon

Comment: The order of events is irrelevant. It’s still a duplicate.

Comment: You have commented on the most recent answer, and now marking as duplicate for improvement. It can be marked as not focused. @SebastianSimon

Answer (score 8, accepted):

<sub>like this?</sub>

SE's flavour of markdown supports HTML sub tags `<sub>like this</sub>`. Some folks also use Unicode small fonts but this is probably easier.

To have a <sup>superscript</sup>, use it `<sup>like this</sup>`.

Comment: So, the `<sub>` attribute can shrink words.

Comment: "Flavour" and "flavor" are both correct ways to spell the word, BTW @Anynobot.

Comment: I tend to favour the british style of spelling 

Comment: @Ollie I was already editing it for other reasons but spell check told me that was wrong, so I corrected it.  I should've known that it was the british way of spelling...

Comment: @loan_2314 It’s an element, not an attribute. It’s also not supposed to be used to _shrink_ words, but to make subscripts, such as H₂O (`H<sub>2</sub>O`). It’s being _abused_ to make text smaller.

Comment: There also isn't a more appropriate substitute for small text, so "abuse" or no, this is a practical and justifiable usage of that tag across Stack Exchange. Go bump [the feature request for `<small>` support](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40035/allow-the-small-tag) if you'd like, the request has been around for nearly as long as the platform itself.